# How does one do a multi table UPDATE in MYSQL 5.1 using ‘ORDER BY’ and ‘LIMIT’ statments

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables **Events** and **FixedPlace**

```
CREATE TABLE  `events` (
  `idEvents` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NumberOfPlaces` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `FpOddsPrice` double DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEvents`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
CREATE TABLE  ` fixedplace ` (
  `idFixedPlacePrice` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NumberOfRunners` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Places` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `FpOddsPrice` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idFixedPlacePrice`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;




Insert Into fixedplace (NumberOfRunners, Places, FpOddsPrice)
Values
(0, 0, 0),
(10, 3, 0.16),
(13, 4, 0.21);
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

To access the fixed place data I use the following statement

```
SELECT
  Places,
  FpOddsPrice
FROM FixedPlace as 
WHERE NumberOfRunners <=  :FNumberOfRunners 
ORDER BY NumberOfRunners desc
LIMIT 1
```

i.e.  If :FNumberOfRunners = 11 then  Place will be 3  and FpOddsPrice = 0.16

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**I am having a problem writing an Update statement
That will update ‘Events’ table based on the values in FixedPlace table**

This does not work

```
UPDATE Events as E, FixedPlace as F 
Set E.Places       = F.Places,
    E.FpOddsPrice  = F.FpOddsPrice
WHERE E.idEvents = :FidEvents
   And F.NumberOfRunners <=  :FNumberOfRunners
ORDER BY F.NumberOfRunners desc
LIMIT 1
```

It gives the following error **‘Incorrect usage of UPDATE an ORDER BY’**

**What must I do to get this to work ?**

**EDIT**

This works - but is there a better way of doing it

```
UPDATE Events as E
Set E.Places       = (Select Places     FROM FixedPlace WHERE NumberOfRunners <=  :FNumberOfRunners ORDER BY NumberOfRunners desc LIMIT 1),
    E.FpOddsPrice    = (Select FpOddsPrice FROM FixedPlace WHERE NumberOfRunners <=  :FNumberOfRunners ORDER BY NumberOfRunners desc LIMIT 1)
WHERE E.idEvents = :FidEvents
```

Comment: How are the two tables connected? I don't see any relationship between them.

Comment: the 'FixedPlace' is a lookup table - and its results are saved in the Events table

Comment: Well, I still don't see it. In the non-working update query you are basically doing a cross join, I'm not sure that's what you want. I'm missing some kind of foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MySQL  UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/update.html) documentation

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE
>   updates rows in each table named in
>   table_references that satisfy the
>   conditions. **In this case, ORDER BY and
>   LIMIT cannot be used**.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: MySQL doesn't allow LIMIT in subqueries either?

Comment: But it does allow them in "unnamed views", so you can do `UPDATE foo SET ... WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (SELECT foo_id FROM bar WHERE ... LIMIT 1) a)`

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hard since MySQL does not allow LIMT in subqueries.

What I'd do is two separate queries.  The first one is already in your post; the second would be a simple UPDATE query like:

```
UPDATE Events E
SET  E.Places = :Places
,    E.FpOddsPrice = :Price
WHERE E.idEvents = :FidEvents
```

Comment: Two queries will work - but for Performance reasons – I would like to use one